# Caching/persisting data in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, caching, design-patterns

During my development career in React, I have seen that we can use multiple kinds of cache/persistance in a RN App.

1. The first one, which is directly provided by react native, is **AsyncStorage**. This allow us to store data in the user device's persistence.
2. Also we can develop our own **in-memory cache**, which can improve the performance of our app by avoiding making unnecessary requests to our server.
3. And the last one, which for me is not a cache, is **React Context**. This tool is cool for having our app routes synchronized. For example, the typical UsersProvider, a context where we can store users data. I have seen some coders using this tool as a "cache" too.

My question here is about clean code. In a React architecture that combines these 3 "tools", how can we correctly delegate the use of all of them to each section of our app?

For example, in a project that have the following folders

```
components/
   auth/
      AuthForm.js


contexts/
    users/
        UsersContext.js


screens/
   Profile/
       EditProfile.js

services/
   api/
      firebase/
         content/
           getContentFeed.js
           cache/
              contentCache.js
   
         users/
             getUserData.js 
             cache/
                 usersCache.js
```

Without looking at the third tool, contexts, which are exclusively consumable/accessible from hooks/components, where should each "memoizer" (AsyncStorage and in-memory caches) be used without violating any pattern or "clean code" rule?

**Is AsyncStorage designed to be used everywhere?** I mean, inside components, hooks, contexts, classes, utils, helpers, apis, ... **with complete freedom?**

**What about in-memory caches?** For example, take a look at my "usersCache.js", where I store the users data that I get from the server. As you can see, I have defined my own api to make requests to the backend... So, if in my "getUserData.js" I am storing/getting/updating data from my cache, to avoid making unnecessary requests, **do you think that using this kind of cache outside the api** (inside components, or anywhere in the frontend) **is product of a bad organization or an anti-pattern?**

Any tips or advices?

Comment: Mmmm interesting